# How to insert data in multiple tables using a prepared statement in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, html, checkbox

I have two tables which are `billing_info, shipping_info`. billing_id is Primary key and billing_id is a foreign key in shipping_info.

I have billing_info address form. The user will fill the billing info, After filling info there is a checkbox which is called as `shipping address is different`. If any user checked that checkbox then it will ask for the shipping information. After filling the shipping information according to the data billing info will store in the billing_info table and shipping_info will store in the shipping info table.

If the user is not checked the checkbox than only billing info will store in the billing info table.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="shipping_status" value="1">
```

I am able to insert the data in the database only for billing_info if the user does not check the checkbox but not able to insert the data after checked the checkbox.
There might be some issue with the query. I tried query is

```
1)  START TRANSACTION;
    INSERT INTO table1 (column name)VALUES (values);
    INSERT INTO table2 (column name) VALUES (values);
    COMMIT;

 2) BEGIN;
    INSERT INTO table1 (column name)VALUES (values);
    INSERT INTO table2 (column name) VALUES (values);
    COMMIT;
```

but still not able to insert the data.
Would you help in out in this?

is this right way to store int user information?

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
  $b_firstname=$conn->real_escape_string(trim($_POST['b_firstname']));
  $b_lastname=$conn->real_escape_string(trim($_POST['b_lastname']));
  $b_address =$conn->real_escape_string(trim($_POST['b_address']));
  $b_country=$conn->real_escape_string(trim($_POST['b_country']));
  $b_state=$conn->real_escape_string(trim($_POST['b_state']));
  $b_city=$conn->real_escape_string(trim($_POST['b_city']));
  $b_pincode=$conn->real_escape_string(trim($_POST['b_pincode']));
  $b_mobileno=$conn->real_escape_string(trim($_POST['b_mobileno']));
  //$login_user_id=$conn->real_escape_string(trim($_POST['login_user_id']));
  //echo $shipping_status=$conn->real_escape_string(trim($_POST['shipping_status']));

  /*Shipping address*/
  $s_firstname=$conn->real_escape_string(trim($_POST['s_firstname']));
  $s_lastname=$conn->real_escape_string(trim($_POST['s_lastname']));
  $s_address =$conn->real_escape_string(trim($_POST['s_address']));
  $s_country=$conn->real_escape_string(trim($_POST['s_country']));
  $s_state=$conn->real_escape_string(trim($_POST['s_state']));
  $s_city=$conn->real_escape_string(trim($_POST['s_city']));
  $s_pincode=$conn->real_escape_string(trim($_POST['s_pincode']));
  $s_mobileno=$conn->real_escape_string(trim($_POST['s_mobileno']));

if (empty($conn->real_escape_string(trim($_POST['shipping_status'])))) {
  $shipping_status=0;
}
else{
$shipping_status=1;
}

if ($shipping_status==0) {

echo $sql="INSERT INTO billing_info (b_firstname, b_lastname, b_address, b_country, b_state, b_city, b_pincode, b_mobileno,login_user_id,shipping_status, b_date_of_added) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,?)";
//  print_r($sql);
  $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->bind_param("ssssssiiiis", $b_firstname, $b_lastname, $b_address, $b_country, $b_state, $b_city, $b_pincode, $b_mobileno,$login_user_id=1,$shipping_status, $date_of_added);

}
else{
  // prepare and bind
  echo $sql="INSERT INTO billing_info (b_firstname, b_lastname, b_address, b_country, b_state, b_city, b_pincode, b_mobileno,login_user_id,shipping_status, b_date_of_added) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,?);INSERT INTO shipping_info (s_firstname, s_lastname, s_address, s_country, s_state, s_city, s_pincode, s_mobileno,b_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);";

  $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->bind_param("ssssssiiiisssssssiii", $b_firstname, $b_lastname, $b_address, $b_country, $b_state, $b_city, $b_pincode, $b_mobileno,$login_user_id=1,$shipping_status, $date_of_added,$s_firstname, $s_lastname, $s_address, $s_country, $s_state, $s_city, $s_pincode, $s_mobileno,LAST_INSERT_ID());

}


  $stmt->execute();
  $stmt->close();

  }

//redirect code
//header('Location: contactus.php');
  $conn->close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, every time you want to insert billing info so Insert query for billing info should not be in if statement.

```
  $sql="INSERT INTO billing_info (b_firstname, b_lastname, b_address, b_country, b_state, b_city, b_pincode, b_mobileno,login_user_id,shipping_status, b_date_of_added) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,?)";
        //  print_r($sql);
          $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
          $stmt->bind_param("ssssssiiiis", $b_firstname, $b_lastname, $b_address, $b_country, $b_state, $b_city, $b_pincode, $b_mobileno,$login_user_id=1,$shipping_status, $date_of_added);
         $stmt->execute();
  $stmt->close();
```

For Shipping status is selected

```
if ($shipping_status==1) {
        $sql="INSERT INTO shipping_info (b_firstname, b_lastname, b_address, b_country, b_state, b_city, b_pincode, b_mobileno,login_user_id,shipping_status, b_date_of_added) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,?)";
        //  print_r($sql);
          $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
          $stmt->bind_param("ssssssiiiis", $b_firstname, $b_lastname, $b_address, $b_country, $b_state, $b_city, $b_pincode, $b_mobileno,$login_user_id=1,$shipping_status, $date_of_added);
 $stmt->execute();
  $stmt->close();
        }
```

Comment: your logic is solved my 80%issues. Now I have to add the order details then where should I add them in the query?

Comment: if it is in another table you can insert it outside of if query.

Answer (score 0):

```
     if (empty($conn->real_escape_string(trim($_POST['shipping_status'])))) {
      $shipping_status=0;
$sql="INSERT INTO billing_info (b_firstname, b_lastname, b_address, b_country, b_state, b_city, b_pincode, b_mobileno,login_user_id,shipping_status, b_date_of_added) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,?)";
//  print_r($sql);
  $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->bind_param("ssssssiiiis", $b_firstname, $b_lastname, $b_address, $b_country, $b_state, $b_city, $b_pincode, $b_mobileno,$login_user_id=1,$shipping_status, $date_of_added);

    }
    else{
    $shipping_status=1;
$sql="INSERT INTO billing_info (b_firstname, b_lastname, b_address, b_country, b_state, b_city, b_pincode, b_mobileno,login_user_id,shipping_status, b_date_of_added) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,?);INSERT INTO shipping_info (s_firstname, s_lastname, s_address, s_country, s_state, s_city, s_pincode, s_mobileno,b_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);";

  $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->bind_param("ssssssiiiisssssssiii", $b_firstname, $b_lastname, $b_address, $b_country, $b_state, $b_city, $b_pincode, $b_mobileno,$login_user_id=1,$shipping_status, $date_of_added,$s_firstname, $s_lastname, $s_address, $s_country, $s_state, $s_city, $s_pincode, $s_mobileno,LAST_INSERT_ID());
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

After `bind_params` you have to insert this

```
$firstname = "John";
$lastname = "Doe";
$email = "john@example.com";
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: You mean to say I have to use $stmt->execute(); inside if-else condition?

Comment: That I already added in my code.but still the same issue. only if the part is working but not able to insert the else part